# Are there any examples of monochrome flags in scripture?

Tags: scripture, war

Flags in scripture usually feature animals - Garuda for Vishnu, the bull for Siva, and so forth.

Are there any other monochrome flags like the Bhagwa flag mentioned in scripture?

Comment: great question. every flag i've heard of always has a symbolic animal or sign, in addition to a color. even kings in kali yug (not mentioned in scriptures) like chera/chola/pandya/maurya had some symbol, not just a plain color.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one, though it's possible it's just because we have a lazy description that leaves out the details rather than giving an actual reflection of the flag.

> O Uttara, yonder auspicious warrior whom you seest cased in coat of tiger-skin and stationed on his car furnished with a **blue-flag** and drawn by red steeds, is **Kripa**.
>
> ---
>
> [[Mahabharata]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc116972.html)

There might be more, though.

Comment: the puri jagannath flag has design elements https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsaOABHomHo

Comment: @SK - oh, I see. I'll remove that one.

Comment: Kṛpācārya's flag has an animal emblem too. It's a bull (vṛṣa). This is stated in Droṇa Parva (105.15), numbering as per Gita Press. KMG's translation is here https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07101.htm
*The preceptor of the Pandavas, that Brahmana, given to ascetic penances, viz., Kripa the son of Gotama, had for his mark an excellent bovine bull. That high-souled one, O king, with that bovine bull, looked as resplendent, as the Destroyer of the three cities.*